# Does Spring.Net have any convention based binding (like Ninject.Extensions.Conventions)

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, spring.net

I am familiar with Ninject, but not Spring.Net. I am trying to determine if there is an equivalent of "Ninject.Extensions.Conventions" in Spring.net.  Something that allows convention based mapping. E.G - Something that will allow me to define a rule like:

- Expect all concrete classes in a given namespace or assembly to have a corresponding interface with the same name, but prefixed with an I.  Automatically map these to each other.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Spring.NET barely has Code as Configuration, so Auto-registration is not available at all.

Answer (score 1):

Spring.net use a different approach, they have CodeConfig that relies in attributes, basically you set some attributes in your classes in order for the DI Container to know what classes need to be injected. You can find more information [here](http://www.springframework.net/codeconfig/doc-latest/reference/html/migration-example.html)

For me the best way to config the IOC is to use an xml file as you can control the behavior of your app without compile anything, even in a production environment.

Answer (score 1):

There is another option using the Spring.AutoRegistration. The same concept used with Unity AutoRegistration.

http://rafaelnaskar.blogspot.com.br/2012/12/springautoregistration-fluent.html

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spring.AutoRegistration

```
    var context = new GenericApplicationContext();
    context.Configure()
            .IncludeAssembly(x => x.FullName.StartsWith("Company.ApplicationXPTO"))
            .Include(x => x.ImplementsITypeName(), Then.Register().UsingSingleton()
                  .InjectByProperty(If.DecoratedWith<InjectAttribute>))
            .ApplyAutoRegistration();

       var context = new GenericApplicationContext();
       context.Configure()
            .Include(If.DecoratedWith<NamedAttribute>,Then.Register().UsingSingleton().InjectByProperty(If.DecoratedWith<InjectAttribute>))
            .Include(If.Implements<IController>, 
                Then.Register().UsingPrototype().InjectByProperty(If.DecoratedWith<InjectAttribute>))
            .ApplyAutoRegistration();



        var context = new GenericApplicationContext();
        context.Configure()
            .IncludeAssembly(x => x.FullName.StartsWith("Spring.AutoRegistration.Test"))
            .Include(x => x.GetInterfaces().Length > 0, 
                Then.Register().WithNamedAttributeIfExists().UsingPrototype()
                    .InjectByProperty(If.DecoratedWith<InjectAttribute>))
            .ApplyAutoRegistration();
```